# Shared access to app registrations on apps.dev.microsoft.com?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have recently registered an app using the new Microsoft registration portal located at apps.dev.microsoft.com, and it all is working great.

However, I am concerned that this registration is tied to my personal account. I would like to grant access to these app registrations to other members of my team. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like when you signed in to the App Registration portal, you used your personal Microsoft account, which ties this *only* to your personal account.

You *can* do what you want, but you will have to re-register your app using a  "work or school" organizational account instead (i.e. Azure AD), and then you can add other users in your organization as additional "owners" of the app.

1. Sign in to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com using your work or school account.
2. Register your app, and copy your Application ID. Because you're signed in with an organizational account, this will result as a new Application object in your organization's Azure AD tenant.
3. Use Azure AD PowerShell to add other owners to the Application object. (Note: Normally I would suggest you use the Azure portal's "App registration" functionality for this, but that view currently filters out apps registered in the App Registration portal.)

   ```bsh
   $AppId = "dc9bc6e6-9893-476f-884f-8bbc1e61f7c5" # <- Your app's Application ID
   $OtherUsername = "bob@contoso.com" # <- Other user who should also own the app

   Connect-AzureAD # <-- Sign in with your organizational account
   $app = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "appId eq '$AppId'" 
   $user = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$OtherUsername'"
   Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -RefObjectId $user.ObjectId
   ```
4. Verify that now both you and the new user are owners of the Application object:

   ```bsh
   Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $app.ObjectId
   ```
5. Now, when the team member you added as an app owner signs in to the App Registration portal (using their organizational account), they will be able to see the app registration.

Comment: That's great, many thanks. We don't have organisational accounts at the moment, but I will look into it.